# Multi Pointer Window Manager

Tags: window-manager, multi-pointer

I test Multi Pointer X (MPX) and I read that there is Multi Pointer Window Manager (MPWM) which has additional fetures to support MPX. The problem is that I can not find MPWM. I googled it and there are only [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.112.8295) and Mutli-Cursor Window Manager in the search results.

Where can I download MPWM?

Comment: I added the link to MPWM to the wikipedia page on MPX, I don't think it currently warrants a page on it own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why your googling did not come up with [this MPWM `git` repository](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~whot/mpwm/), but that should help you on your way.

From the `README` there:

```
MPWM is the multi-pointer window manager, a MPX-aware window manager that
supports window operations from multiple devices.

MPWM is a proof-of-concept, not a real window manager. It's lacking most
features that you'd expect from a window manager so don't use it in
production. Or on your desktop. Or really anywhere.

It's also unmaintained, I just keep it here because the source can be of
value to someone.
```